# Error "public.powa_take_snapshot()" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am observing this error in the log of my PostgreSQL 12:

```
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:LOG:  POWA connected to database powa
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:ERROR:  query returned more than one row
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:HINT:  Make sure the query returns a single row, or use LIMIT 1.
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function powa_take_snapshot(integer) line 31 at SQL statement
        SQL statement "SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot()"
2023-10-07 16:03:06 UTC:LOG:  background worker "powa" (PID 34049) exited with exit code 1
```

I have tried to restart the DB but the error appears again. If I launch the SELECT statement "[local] postgres@postgres=# SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot();" I get this error:

```
"ERROR: function public.powa_take_snapshot() does not exist".
LINE 1: SELECT public.powa_take_snapshot()
               ^
TIP: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add an explicit type conversion".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a buggy statement in the function code. You should report this problem to the authors of the extension.